# Android: can not set onItemListener

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I am creating a ListView with an adapter in an intent with a dialogtheme:

```
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, test_list, R.layout.list_layout2, from, to);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Then I am trying to add some listeners, but they aren't triggered in the running app.

```
    onclick =new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("item",arg2 + "");
        }

    };

    onlongclick = new OnItemLongClickListener(){


        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("longitem",arg2 + "");
            return false;
        }

    };

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(onclick);

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(onlongclick);
```

Does anybody have an suggestion to get things running correctly?

Comment: Try adding a `+` to `Log.d("item",arg2 + "");` and `Log.d("longitem",arg2 + "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. 
In my item layout "R.layout.list_layout2" was a TextView with

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Deleting this got my OnItemClickListener work stable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be correct, but what i dont understand is why you make variables of your listeners? 
You can just set them.

Check out the link here:

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1351248

It uses ArrayAdapter instead of SimpleAdapter and one of the parameters is the items.

It might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I've found tutorial that might help you with your problem

Check out here

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-simple-listview-tutorial/